# Java for loop to print each month of the year

Tags: java, for-loop

The follow java code will print the numbers 1- 10 starting at 1. How can I use this same code structure to print out all of the months of the year only once so January, February, March, etc?

```
public class s {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);          
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well for one, there are 12 months in a year so you would have to edit it slightly. What have you tried so far, besides this loop?

Comment: you can store the months name into an array , and use a simple `for` to print the months

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this the old fashion way and a little more hands on for learning arrays:

```
String[] months = new String[] { "January", "February", "March" };

for (int i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(months[i]);
}
```

Or to be a little more concise:

```
for (String month : months) {
    System.out.println(month);
}
```

You can learn more about arrays, and check out some tutorials in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Answer (score 6):

If you want to relay on java api use:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    // java 8
    Arrays.stream(Month.values())
          .forEach(System.out::println);

    // java < 8
    for (final Month month : Month.values()) {
        System.out.println(month);
    }
}
```

Comment: Judging by the content of the OP, streams might be a little much.

Comment: As for “java < 8”, like streams and lambdas, the `Month` enum arrived in Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

## `Month`

The [best correct Answer is by staszek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39903303/642706) making clever use of Streams. Here's the same idea but in old-fashioned syntax instead of Streams, plus some comments.

The [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) defines a dozen instances, one per month of the year, numbered sanely 1-12 for January-December. The [`Month.getValues`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html#values--) method returns an array of all twelve instances. We can loop that array using the Java syntax for the ”enhanced `for` loop” also known as a “for-each”.

You can ask for a localized name of the month via the [`getDisplayName`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html#getDisplayName-java.time.format.TextStyle-java.util.Locale-) method. Specify a `TextStyle` for length of abbreviation, and a `Locale` for the human language and cultural norms used in translating.

```
TextStyle ts = TextStyle.FULL;
Locale l = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH;

for ( Month month : Month.values () ) {
    int monthNumber = month.getValue (); // 1-12.
    String monthName = month.getDisplayName ( ts , l );
    System.out.println ( "month: " + month + " | monthNumber: " + monthNumber + " | monthName: " + monthName );
}
```

```
month: JANUARY | monthNumber: 1 | monthName: janvier
month: FEBRUARY | monthNumber: 2 | monthName: février
month: MARCH | monthNumber: 3 | monthName: mars
month: APRIL | monthNumber: 4 | monthName: avril
month: MAY | monthNumber: 5 | monthName: mai
month: JUNE | monthNumber: 6 | monthName: juin
month: JULY | monthNumber: 7 | monthName: juillet
month: AUGUST | monthNumber: 8 | monthName: août
month: SEPTEMBER | monthNumber: 9 | monthName: septembre
month: OCTOBER | monthNumber: 10 | monthName: octobre
month: NOVEMBER | monthNumber: 11 | monthName: novembre
month: DECEMBER | monthNumber: 12 | monthName: décembre
```

See [Oracle Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) for:

- [Enum types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)
- [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/)
- [Streams](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html) and [lambdas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Would you try this

```
String[] months = new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths();
for (int i = 0; i <12; i++) {
     System.out.println("month = " + months[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
String[] months = new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths();
    for(String singleMonth: months){
        System.out.println(singleMonth);
    }
```